# Count the numbers of integer solutions of the ecuation $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 21$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, integer-partitions

How to count the number of nonnegative integer solutions to $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 21$ such that $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$, $x_4 ≤ 7$

Comment: Count the solutions if you don't care about the upper bound.  Apply inclusion-exclusion based on if any violated the upper bound conditions noting it is possible for multiple to violate simultaneously.

Comment: Two reasons why I can't give a meaningful hint/answer:  [1] You have shown no work [2] All of the concepts that I would utilize have been captured in the pre-existing comments of J Moravitz and Dietrich Burde, above.  What I can *comment* is that [this Stars and Bars article](https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/) will be helpful.

Comment: I have counted $120$ solutions.

Comment: @user2661923 Why? It is just a comment. It should lead to a wider partecipation of OP who seems like vanished. I am Notheist, tho :D

Comment: @DietrichBurde I deleted my comment - you're right.  I **incorrectly** assumed that the person giving the comment was the OP, and reacted in frustration.

Comment: @user2661923 No problem, this happened to me several times, too. I will delete my comments, too, if you agree.

Answer (score 1):

If you think about it you can see that you want the coefficient of $x^{21}$ in the expansion of $(1+x+x^2+\cdots + x^7)^4.$ I don't know an easy way to get that, but on a symbolic algebra calculator the coefficient is $120.$

Comment: There are generally two approaches to this type of question, Stars and Bars (as suggested by the comments following the query) and generating functions.  I know that Stars and Bars (+ Inclusion-Exclusion) yields the following computation, and I suspect that generating functions does as well: $$\binom{24}{3} - 4\binom{16}{3} + 6\binom{8}{3}.$$  Note that $\binom{24}{3}$ represents $\binom{n+[k-1]}{k-1}$, and that if **more** than 2 of the variables exceed $7$, then the sum can not be less than $24$.

Comment: In the above comment, the expression $\binom{16}{3}$ represents $x_1 + \cdots + x_4 = 21$ **and** $x_1 \geq 8$ which **bijects** to $x_1 + \cdots x_4 = 13$ **and** each of the variables is non-negative.  The coefficients $\binom{4}{1}$ and $\binom{4}{2}$ represent the number of ways of selecting which single variable or which pair of variables will violate the constraint by **each** being $\geq 8.$

Comment: @user2661923 I see what you're getting at.

Comment: @user2661923 Just checked and your method also gives 120. Thanks.